# modelagem 0..1 para 1 no Entity Framework - Erro The entity or complex

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta linq, mas retorna o erro:

> Additional information: The entity or complex type
>   'WMB.CieloB.Model.CieloToken' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to
>   Entities query.

A minha consulta:

```
    var temp = (from tok in db.CieloTokens
             join rec in db.CieloRecorrencias
             on tok.CieloRecorrenciaId equals rec.CieloRecorrenciaId 
             where rec.ClienteId == IDC && tok.ClienteId == IDC && tok.CieloRecorrenciaId > 0
             select new CieloToken()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Minhas 2 models (removi algumas propriedades/atributos para diminuir o post):

```
  public class CieloToken
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("CieloRecorrencia")]
        [Column("int_ID")]
        public int CieloTokenId { get; set; }

        [Column("int_IDC")]
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        [Column("str_Token")]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Token { get; set; }

        public int? CieloRecorrenciaId { get; set; }

        public virtual CieloRecorrencia CieloRecorrencia { get; set; }

    }

public class CieloRecorrencia
{
    [Key]
    [Column("int_ID")]
    public int CieloRecorrenciaId { get; set; }

    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public virtual CieloToken cieloToken { get; set; }
}
```

Tentei fazer com LAMBDA

```
    var teste_Capeta = db.CieloTokens
            .Include(i => i.CieloRecorrencia)
            .FirstOrDefault(w => w.ClienteId == IDC && w.CieloRecorrencia.ClienteId == IDC && w.CieloRecorrenciaId > 0);
```

Ai o valor é `null`, sendo que existe os registros.

OBS: no Where coloquei 2 campos iguais (ClienteId), de tabelas diferentes só para garantir e nos testes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema está na hora que você faz um `select new CieloToken()`.

Tente dessa forma:

```
var temp = (from tok in db.CieloTokens
             join rec in db.CieloRecorrencias
             on tok.CieloRecorrenciaId equals rec.CieloRecorrenciaId 
             where rec.ClienteId == IDC && tok.ClienteId == IDC && tok.CieloRecorrenciaId > 0
             select tok).FirstOrDefault();
```

Assim você vai retornar o registro que a consulta do banco retornar. Se você precisar de informações do join você pode criar um objeto anônimo.

Já a linha `where rec.ClienteId == IDC && tok.ClienteId == IDC` pode ser o motivo de você não obter resultado. Você não precisa da propriedade `public int? CieloRecorrenciaId { get; set; }`, o mapeamento do relacionamento já está sendo feito na classe `CieloRecorrencia`